# VS 2008 Web Application Issue when site is published

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Hi I have a VS 2008 web app, that runs on my local machine fine, and as system admin runs fine on the server, but none of the users can run it, the error indicates that the dll is looking for files with the explicit path from my PC not the unc path on the Server.

Any advice greatly appreciated, I know I must be over looking something simple

Answer (score 0):

Are You using any paths directly in Your application code?
Are You using any third party components with configuration set-up in web.config?

Check this out first.